# my music overlap how to stop that in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this code in javascript .. i want it to work in every single song in my songs variable ..any help on how to do it
thanks

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let songs = document.querySelectorAll(".song");
    let sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section button");
   //song start play
    
    sections.forEach((button, index) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
         if(songs[index].paused){
           songs[index].play(); 
        } else{
            songs[index].pause(); 
        }
     });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On button click, if the song is at pause, play it... But you also need to makes sure all other songs are paused.

You just need an additional `forEach` loop to pause them all before playing the one associated with the clicked button.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let songs = document.querySelectorAll(".song");
    let sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section button");
   //song start play
    
    sections.forEach((button, index) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
         if(songs[index].paused){
         
           songs.forEach(song => song.pause())  // This will pause all songs
         
           songs[index].play(); 
        } else{
            songs[index].pause(); 
        }
     });
    });
});
```

```css
audio{
  display: none;
}
button{
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <audio controls class="song" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"></audio>
  <button class="button">Play song #1</button>
</div>
  <div class="section">
    <audio controls class="song" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3"></audio>
  <button class="button">Play song #2</button>
</div>
    <div class="section">
  <audio controls class="song" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3"></audio>
  <button class="button">Play song #3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thannnnnk u sooo much its work just by adding this                                   
          songs.forEach(song => song.pause())                                                                                  i hope i will become like u some day ... thank u so much